# Return true or false via a function and a calculation by slice/spacing of 10

Tags: javascript, function

Here is an example of a calculation I would like to do:

```
var total_lines = 0;
```

Imagine I write a line:

```
1: Test
```

Then my variable total_line will become 1.

Imagine that I write 10 lines, total_lines will become 10 and here is the right moment to return "true" via a function but afterwards it must return "false" each time.

Imagine that I continue, we still write 9 lines, so total_lines will become "19".

I still write a line and there in the 20th the function must return to me "true".

In fact, I'm looking for a function that returns "true" every time it finds a number for every 10.

Do you have an idea ?

Example:

```
0 = false
1 to 9 = false
10 = true
11 to 19 = false
20 = true
21 to 29 = false
30 = true
31 to 39 = false
...
100 = true
101 = false
...
```

Comment: Probably the *remainder* operator `%`: `if (num % 10 == 0) ...`.

Comment: `return num && num%10===0`

Comment: @vibhor1997a - true for 0 too

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot the 0 case :)

Comment: @vibhor1997a `return total_lines && !(total_lines % 10)`

Comment: @mplungjan won't this be somewhat unreadable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write a function that returns true when `total_lines % 10` is 0, where `%` is the [`remainder operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_())

```
function calLines(total_lines) {
    if(total_lines > 0 && total_lines % 10 === 0) {
       return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

or simply as @mplungjan pointed out in the comments, you can make use of `&&` operator

```
function calLines(total_lines) {
    return total_lines > 0 && total_lines % 10 === 0
}
```

Comment: Please do not waste time testing a boolean function `function calLines(total_lines) {
     return total_lines > 0 && total_lines % 10 === 0;
}`

Comment: @mplungjan, yes your way is a shorter way but for starters I feel if-else is more readable

Comment: @mplungjan—I'm not a fan of function expressions where a declaration will do, but exceptions make the rule: `let calLines = total_lines => total_lines && total_lines % 10 === 0`. ;-)

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri—fair comment, but given the logic is encapsulated in the *if* expression, it's reasonable to just return the value of the expression, so less to read and fewer keystrokes so fewer opportunities for typos. ;-) In the end it's personal preference.

Comment: `return total_lines && !(total_lines % 10)`;)

Comment: And maybe OP is a starter so please also add a link or something for `%` operator and explanation how this works.

Comment: The use of the term "modulo operator" is incorrect. The ECMAScript remainder operator `%` does not return the correct value for modulo operations where either operand is negative, hence it's called the *remainder* operator.

Comment: I'm not good at calculating that's why I came here, I took the one from @mplungjan it is shorter, thank you.

Comment: So I arranged a little so that it looks like this: return ((total_lines > 0 && total_lines % 10 === 0) ? true : false);

Comment: @jacke A ternary is not needed when the intermediate result is a Boolean - just `return total_lines > 0 && total_lines % 10 === 0;`